# Extract Date, Append by Number of Games

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently web scraping the college football schedule by week.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.cbssports.com/college-football/schedule/FBS/2020/regular/5/'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

teams = [t.text for t in soup.find_all('span', class_='TeamName')]
away = teams[::2]
home = teams[1::2]

time = [c.text.replace("\n", "").replace('                    ','').replace('        ',' ') for c in soup.find_all('div', class_='CellGame')]

import pandas as pd
schedule = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'away': away,
     'home': home,
     'time': time,
    })
schedule
```

I would like a date column. I am having difficulty extracting the date and duplicate the date corresponding to number of games for that date and append to a python list.

```
date = []
for d in soup.find_all('div', class_='TableBaseWrapper'):
  for a in d.find_all('h4'):
    date.append(a.text.replace('\n                            \n    ','').replace('\n                    \n                                    ',''))
print(date)
```

`['Friday, October 2, 2020', 'Saturday, October 3, 2020']`

Dates are like headers for each table. I would like each date corresponding to the correct game. And also include "postponed' for the postponed games.

My plan is to automate this code for each week.

Thanks ahead.

*Post Answer

Beautiful and well done. How would I pull venues especially with postponed, using your code?
My original code was:

```
venue = [v.text.replace('\n','').replace('                    ','').replace('                ','').strip('—').strip() for v in soup.find_all('td', text=lambda x: x and "Field" or x and 'Stadium' in x) if v != '' ]
venues = [x for x in venue if x]

missing = len(away) - len(venues)
words = ['Postponed' for x in range(missing) if len(away)> len(venues)]
venues = venues + words
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Your posted code merely loads and prepares the data.  In a "proper" Stack Overflow question, this would be a hard-coded DF load (i.e. reproducible), because the input process is not part of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.find_previous()` to find date for current tow:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.cbssports.com/college-football/schedule/FBS/2020/regular/5/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for row in soup.select('.TableBase-bodyTr'):
    home = row.select_one('.TeamLogoNameLockup')
    away = home.find_next(class_='TeamLogoNameLockup')
    time = row.select_one('.CellGame')
    date = row.find_previous('h4')

    all_data.append({
        'home': home.get_text(strip=True),
        'away': away.get_text(strip=True),
        'time': time.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '),
        'date': date.get_text(strip=True),
    })


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                home              away                            time                       date
0           Campbell       Wake Forest               WAKE 66 - CAMP 14    Friday, October 2, 2020
1     Louisiana Tech               BYU              BYU 45 - LATECH 14    Friday, October 2, 2020
2      East Carolina       Georgia St.      GAST 35, ECU 10 - 2nd ESPU  Saturday, October 3, 2020
3       Arkansas St.  Coastal Carolina  CSTCAR 17, ARKST 14 - 2nd ESP2  Saturday, October 3, 2020
4           Missouri         Tennessee    TENN 21, MIZZOU 6 - 2nd SECN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
5             Baylor     West Virginia       BAYLOR 7, WVU 7 - 2nd ABC  Saturday, October 3, 2020
6                TCU             Texas      TCU 14, TEXAS 14 - 2nd FOX  Saturday, October 3, 2020
7           NC State        Pittsburgh     NCST 17, PITT 10 - 2nd ACCN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
8     South Carolina           Florida        FLA 17, SC 14 - 2nd ESPN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
9     UT-San Antonio               UAB             UAB 7, TXSA 3 - 2nd  Saturday, October 3, 2020
10     North Alabama           Liberty         NAL 0, LIB 0 - 1st ESP3  Saturday, October 3, 2020
11    Abil Christian              Army                   1:30 pm CBSSN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
12         Texas A&M           Alabama                         3:30 pm  Saturday, October 3, 2020
13        Texas Tech        Kansas St.                     3:30 pm FS1  Saturday, October 3, 2020
14    North Carolina    Boston College                     3:30 pm ABC  Saturday, October 3, 2020
15     South Florida        Cincinnati                    3:30 pm ESP+  Saturday, October 3, 2020
16      Oklahoma St.            Kansas                    3:30 pm ESPN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
17           Memphis               SMU                    3:30 pm ESP2  Saturday, October 3, 2020
18         Charlotte               FAU                    4:00 pm ESPU  Saturday, October 3, 2020
19  Jacksonville St.       Florida St.                         4:00 pm  Saturday, October 3, 2020
20     Virginia Tech              Duke                    4:00 pm ACCN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
21          Ole Miss          Kentucky                    4:00 pm SECN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
22       W. Kentucky      Middle Tenn.                    5:00 pm ESP3  Saturday, October 3, 2020
23              Navy         Air Force                   6:00 pm CBSSN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
24      Ga. Southern         UL-Monroe                    7:00 pm ESP+  Saturday, October 3, 2020
25            Auburn           Georgia                    7:30 pm ESPN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
26          Arkansas       Miss. State                    7:30 pm SECN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
27               LSU        Vanderbilt                    7:30 pm SECN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
28          Oklahoma          Iowa St.                     7:30 pm ABC  Saturday, October 3, 2020
29          So. Miss       North Texas                         7:30 pm  Saturday, October 3, 2020
30             Tulsa               UCF                    7:30 pm ESP2  Saturday, October 3, 2020
31          Virginia           Clemson                    8:00 pm ACCN  Saturday, October 3, 2020
32              Rice          Marshall                       Postponed  Saturday, October 3, 2020
33              Troy     South Alabama                       Postponed  Saturday, October 3, 2020
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

---

EDIT: To pare "Venue" column, you can use this example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.cbssports.com/college-football/schedule/FBS/2020/regular/5/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for row in soup.select('.TableBase-bodyTr'):
    home = row.select_one('.TeamLogoNameLockup')
    away = home.find_next(class_='TeamLogoNameLockup')
    time = row.select_one('.CellGame')
    venue = '-' if len(row.select('td')) == 3 else row.select('td')[3].get_text(strip=True)
    date = row.find_previous('h4')

    all_data.append({
        'home': home.get_text(strip=True),
        'away': away.get_text(strip=True),
        'time': time.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '),
        'venue': venue,
        'date': date.get_text(strip=True),
    })


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                home              away                            time                                        venue                       date
0           Campbell       Wake Forest               WAKE 66 - CAMP 14                                            -    Friday, October 2, 2020
1     Louisiana Tech               BYU              BYU 45 - LATECH 14                                            -    Friday, October 2, 2020
2      East Carolina       Georgia St.      GAST 35, ECU 13 - 3rd ESPU                          Center Parc Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
3       Arkansas St.  Coastal Carolina  CSTCAR 31, ARKST 14 - 3rd ESP2                               Brooks Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
4           Missouri         Tennessee    TENN 28, MIZZOU 6 - 3rd SECN                              Neyland Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
5             Baylor     West Virginia       BAYLOR 7, WVU 7 - 3rd ABC    Mountaineer Field at Milan Puskar Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
6                TCU             Texas      TCU 20, TEXAS 14 - 2nd FOX                   DKR-Texas Memorial Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
7           NC State        Pittsburgh     NCST 17, PITT 13 - 3rd ACCN                                  Heinz Field  Saturday, October 3, 2020
8     South Carolina           Florida        FLA 31, SC 14 - 3rd ESPN    Florida Field at Ben Hill Griffin Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
9     UT-San Antonio               UAB            UAB 14, TXSA 6 - 2nd                                 Legion Field  Saturday, October 3, 2020
10     North Alabama           Liberty         LIB 7, NAL 0 - 2nd ESP3                             Williams Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
11    Abil Christian              Army      ARMY 7, ABIL 0 - 1st CBSSN                Blaik Field at Michie Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
12         Texas A&M           Alabama                         3:30 pm                         Bryant-Denny Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
13        Texas Tech        Kansas St.                     3:30 pm FS1                   Bill Snyder Family Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
14    North Carolina    Boston College                     3:30 pm ABC                               Alumni Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
15     South Florida        Cincinnati                    3:30 pm ESP+                              Nippert Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
16      Oklahoma St.            Kansas                    3:30 pm ESPN          David Booth Kansas Memorial Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
17           Memphis               SMU                    3:30 pm ESP2                       Gerald J. Ford Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
18         Charlotte               FAU                    4:00 pm ESPU                                  FAU Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
19  Jacksonville St.       Florida St.                         4:00 pm  Bobby Bowden Field at Doak Campbell Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
20     Virginia Tech              Duke                    4:00 pm ACCN         Brooks Field at Wallace Wade Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
21          Ole Miss          Kentucky                    4:00 pm SECN                                 Kroger Field  Saturday, October 3, 2020
22       W. Kentucky      Middle Tenn.                    5:00 pm ESP3                   Johnny (Red) Floyd Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
23              Navy         Air Force                   6:00 pm CBSSN                               Falcon Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
24      Ga. Southern         UL-Monroe                    7:00 pm ESP+         JPS Field at James L. Malone Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
25            Auburn           Georgia                    7:30 pm ESPN                              Sanford Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
26          Arkansas       Miss. State                    7:30 pm SECN            Davis Wade Stadium at Scott Field  Saturday, October 3, 2020
27               LSU        Vanderbilt                    7:30 pm SECN                           Vanderbilt Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
28          Oklahoma          Iowa St.                     7:30 pm ABC                           Jack Trice Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
29          So. Miss       North Texas                         7:30 pm                               Apogee Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
30             Tulsa               UCF                    7:30 pm ESP2                             Spectrum Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
31          Virginia           Clemson                    8:00 pm ACCN                             Memorial Stadium  Saturday, October 3, 2020
32              Rice          Marshall                       Postponed                                            -  Saturday, October 3, 2020
33              Troy     South Alabama                       Postponed                                            -  Saturday, October 3, 2020
```

Comment: Beautiful and well done. How would I pull venues especially with postponed, using your code? My original code was: 

venue = [v.text.replace('\n','').replace('                    ','').replace('                ','').strip('—').strip() for v in soup.find_all('td', text=lambda x: x and "Field" or x and 'Stadium' in x) if v != '' ]
venues = [x for x in venue if x]

missing = len(away) - len(venues)
words = ['Postponed' for x in range(missing) if len(away)> len(venues)]
venues = venues + words